# Custom Actionbar doesn't override default Actionbar

Tags: android, android-custom-view, custom-view

I implemented custom action bar which contains an image and button. It is working fine but this custom actionbar gets displayed below main action bar.How should i override it on main bar.Please don't get confused with app name or title. [image: Sample image]

Code for MainActivity.java

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    ActionBar actionBar = getSupportActionBar();
    View v1 = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.custom_drawer_item, null);
    actionBar.setCustomView(v1);
}
}
```

Code for customlayout

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="70dp"
android:background="#00897B" >


<Button
    android:layout_width="190dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Register an event"
    android:textColor="#ffffff"
    android:background="#4db6ac"
    android:id="@+id/button1"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />

<ImageView
    android:layout_width="40dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/imageView1"
    android:src="@drawable/refr"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
    android:layout_marginEnd="32dp" />


</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

U need u set action bar in toolbar as u are using AppCompatActivity.

Search for toolbar , use it. It has a method using which u can set actionbar.

In your screenshot black part is toolbar .

And green part is action bar.

Toolbar is new design as per material guidelines, action bar is deprecated.

Answer (score 0):

As Priya say, use ToolBar, and extends ActionBarActivity

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity{

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
       super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
       setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

       Toolbar toolBar = (Toolbar)findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
       setSupportActionBar(toolBar);
   }
}
```